# Comparing Arrays to find the difference [Filehandling in Perl]

Tags: arrays, perl, design-patterns, matching

I exported some Files and after the Export there are actually 2 Files missing.
In the Report is written that I exported 260 Files but I only got 258.

Now I want to check which File is missing. So I decided to try it with a Perl Script, even tho im pretty new to this.

The Export Protocol Looks like this...

> DATEDATEDATE - USER EXPORT, counter '0000000001': Object:
>   'FILENAME' got exported. DATEDATEDATE- USER EXPORT.
>   File: 'D:\Work\Export_Import\Export\FILENAME.xml' exported.

The only important Thing is the Filename :]

Thank you!

Edit: Solved it. Scroll down :]

Comment: You change $Expo for every line in DATEI. Only the last value is preserved when the loop ends.

Comment: yes, you're resetting $Expo every time through the loop. use the concatenate operator `.=` instead of `=`. although... I think you still have problems after that.

Comment: Fixed that already, Thanks. But the Problem is somewhere else in the logic probly. I doubt I can use !~ here :D

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is this line:

```
$Expo = $Export . $_;
```

You're concatenating all your filenames into a single scalar, which isn't going to work very well. Because you'll only ever have the last one there... and especially if `$Export` is a directory, that you're trying to open as a file.

Can I suggest instead using `File::Find`? A bit like this:

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

#Pragmas
use strict;
use warnings;

my %files_in_dir;
my %files_in_export;

my $dir_name    = '/path/to/dir';
my $export_name = 'filename_here';

sub find_files {
    if (-f) {
        $files_in_dir{$_} = $File::Find::name;
    }
}

find( \&find_files, $dir_name );

#Open Export File
open( my $datei, "<", "$export_name" ) or die $!;
while ( my $filename = <$datei> ) {
    chomp($filename);
    if ( $files_in_dir{$filename} ) {
        print "$filename in $files_in_dir{$filename}\n";
    }
    else {
        print "No $filename found\n";
    }
}
close($datei);
```

I would also suggest:

- use 3 argument open, with lexical vars.

Answer (score 0):

create a hash index of the successfully exported files (assuming all files are in one directory, and the full paths are not important):

```
my $dir = 'some/dir';
opendir my $dh, $dir;
my @files = readdir $dh;   
my %index;
$index{$_} = 1 foreach @files;
```

now iterate though the "protocol" file and capture the exported filename on each line. use that filename to see if it exists as a key in the hash you created earlier.

```
# open your protocol file, then...
while (<$protocol_fh>) {
    my $exported = $1 if $_ =~ /([^\/]+\.xml)/;
    print "$exported was not found in $dir\n" if ! $index{$exported};
}
```

Note that you will have to test that regex to capture the filename from the protocol file, as I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Pragmas
use strict;
use warnings;

#Variablen
my $dir_name ='PathToDir';
my $export_name ='File.txt';

my $re1 = '.*?';
my $re2 = '((?:[a-z][a-z\\.\\d_]+)\\.(?:[a-z\\d]{3}))(?![\\w\\.])';
my @array1;
my @array2;
my $fqdn1;
my @diff;
my @isect;
my $item;
my %count;

#Open Report
open( my $fh, '<', $export_name )
  or die "Could not open file '$export_name' $!";

    while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $row;
    my $re = $re1 . $re2;
    if ( $row =~ m/$re/is ) {
        $fqdn1 = $1;

        if ( $fqdn1 =~ m/xml/ ) {
            push( @array1, $fqdn1 );
        }
    }

}
close($fh);

#Open Directory
opendir DIR, $dir_name;
@array2 = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir(DIR);
close(DIR);

#Searching the difference
@isect = ();
@diff  = ();
%count = ();

foreach $item ( @array1, @array2 ) { $count{$item}++; }

foreach $item ( keys %count ) {
    if ( $count{$item} == 2 ) {
        push @isect, $item;
    }
    else {
        push @diff, $item;
    }
}

#Output
print "Missing Filenames = @diff\n\n";

# print "\nA Array = @array1\n";
# print "\nB Array = @array2\n";
# print "\nIntersect Array = @isect\n";
```

I solved it. Thanks to everyone.